# Tty and X session locking

Tags: linux, xorg, tty

Most GUIs lock the session after a period of idleness or after resuming from sleep, which means that the user is require to reauthenticate themselves to continue the session.

Can this be mirrored in the virtual consoles and can the two by kept in sync? (i.e., the X session of user x and tty sessions of user x shouldn't lock up if user x is not idle on at least one tty session or X session).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are three alternatives:

**vlock**: (it is in the repos of most distros),

> Virtual Console locking program
>
> vlock either locks the current terminal (which may be any kind of
>    terminal, local or remote), or locks the entire virtual console
>    system, completely disabling all console access.  vlock gives up
>    these locks when either the password of the user who started vlock
>    or the root password is typed.

[**physlock**](https://github.com/muennich/physlock)

> Control physical access to a linux computer by locking all of its virtual terminals / consoles.
>
> physlock is an alternative to vlock, it is equivalent to `vlock -an'. It is written because vlock blocks some linux kernel mechanisms like hibernate and suspend and can therefore only be used with some limitations. physlock is designed to be more lightweight, it does not have a plugin interface and it is not started using a shell script wrapper.

[**bashlock**](https://github.com/acornejo/bashlock)

> bash script to lock the console.
>
> It requires the password of the calling user to unlock the console. This utility is similar in spirit to vlock, the only reason it exists is because vlock was unavailable for OS X.
>
> The main purpose of bashlock is to be used as a lock-server inside tmux. This allow you the user to lock tmux sessions.